# XMLHttpRequest loads but fails to load

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I know the title is contradictory but bear with me.

I have a simple XMLHttpRequest in an MVC app hosted on Azure:-

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        
xhttp.open("GET","http://isni.oclc.org/sru/DB=1.2/query=pica.na+%3DPrince", 
           false);
xhttp.send();
</script>
```

this results in a 200 code response and I can see the return page (XML data) using Chrome Network panel. However, I also get the following 2 errors (in the Chrome Console):-

1) Failed to load http://isni.oclc.org/sru/DB=1.2/?query=pica.na+%3DPrince: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mhdatamodel.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.
loadDoc @ HttpRequest:153
onclick @ HttpRequest:89

2) Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://isni.oclc.org/sru/DB=1.2/?query=pica.na+%3DPrince'.

My question is how did I get exactly the response I was expecting (the XML data, the same as if I had just entered the http://... into my browser) and yet get a "Failed to load..." and a  "Failed to execute 'send'..." error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to look up [CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues, and how to allow CORS from your backend

Comment: If it is a CORS issue why would the server deliver exactly the page I want and would get if I just used a browser? Surely if this is a CORS issue the server would respond, after the pre flight request,  and just refuse to serve the page I requested? It didn't, I got the page I wanted along with the errors!

Comment: I should have mentioned I have previously read the page you suggested, amongst many others of similar detail. However, it and they do not cover the situation I have i.e. the page is delivered, so apparently no CORS issue, but then I get the 2 errors mentioned which hint at a CORS issue.

Comment: Your *browser* gets the response just fine — that’s why you can see it in the Network panel. But just because your browser can get it doesn’t mean the browser will expose it to your frontend JavaScript code. Your browser will do that only if the response includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the right value. Otherwise, your browser blocks your frontend JavaScript code from accessing the response. That’s the way CORS works.

Comment: Thanks sideshowbarker. So that I am clear, is the ACAO response you mentioned, a result of a preflight request? If not, are you saying that the request is supplied to the browser  (i.e. the XML page in this case) along with an ACAO response header that says, oh btw you don't have permission to past this to the viewer of the browser?  Why go to the trouble of sending what could be lots of data across the wire if the server is disallowing the passing on of the same. Apologies if I am being a bit dim here